# Ibeacon app developing

Tags: iphone, ios7, ibeacon

Just started reading about this ibeacon that apple is selling out to retailers. If I wanted to created an app that connects to these beacons.. how can I do so? Cant seem to find any apis or any help for doing this, it is a relatively new technology. Also, can Android devices also utilize this technology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has an app called AirLocate that they released at WWDC this year. If you search on "AirLocate" you can find it online.

It is an app that lets you turn your BLE-capable iOS device (iPhone 4S or later, iPad mini/ iPad 3 or later, or 4" iPod) into either a beacon or a beacon detector.

With that source it's quite easy to figure out the basics of iBeacon programming.

As the other poster said, the newest Androids are able to detect beacons, but so far the firmware does not support sending as a beacon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Android devices can interact with iBeacons using Radius Networks' [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/).

You can find a table that compares the APIs for both Android and iOS [on this page](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/documentation.html).  You may also want to Google for a tutorial.